# GitlabCI not using variable

Tags: .net-core, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm keeping my connectionString in application secrets and it works if I'm deploying from my own computer. Now, I'd like to store this value as GitlabCI Variable and use it during deployment. In order to achieve that I did following steps:

Created CONNECTION_STRING variable in GitlabCI
[image]

Modified `.gitlab-ci.yml` to use this variable

```
before_script:
  - 'dotnet user-secrets set "ConnectionString" %CONNECTION_STRING%'
build:
 stage: build
 script:
  - 'dotnet build -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Properties/PublishProfiles/MyPublishProfile.pubxml'
```

Modified `Startup.cs` class to use this secret

```
 private IConfiguration SecretConfiguration { get; }

 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
     SecretConfiguration = configuration;
 }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddCors();
     services.AddDbContext<StudentRepository>(options =>
          options.UseMySQL(SecretConfiguration["ConnectionString"]));        
     services.AddMvc();        
 }
```

Deployment is successful, but connection isn't set up properly. When I hit endpoint that searches something in database, I'm getting

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   connectionString    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value,
>   String parameterName)

Comment: try to print the env in the before_script/script to check if the issue is missing env or that the env can't reach the build command

Comment: Well, during deployment the key is created like I want. I can print it like you suggested. But I figured something else... correct me if I'm wrong, creating app secret during deployment creates it on deployer machine and once deployment is done, and application starts on external host and the secrets are not there. So whole idea I got was a misstake?

Comment: you should be able to access the secrets inside the stage

Comment: You are saying that secrets are applied to my application during build stage? Well, then something isn't working as expected... All keys stored in secrets are `null` after depoyment. If I store them on my local computer and just type `dotnet run` - it works fine.

Comment: I think you need to use `$CONNECTION_STRING` instead of `%CONNECTION_STRING%`

Comment: It runs on Windows OS, so `%CONNECTION_STRING%` is fine. AFAIK `$` works on Unix

Comment: @Weeedooo But have you eventually tried using `$`? If you are using public GitLab Runners then you should use `$`. If you are hosting your own GitLab Runner instance then use notation suitable for OS on which the runner is hosted.